# Access field from class where list belong to

Tags: c#

let say i have following class:

```
class Shape
{
    public int widht;

    public List<Point> points;
}
```

and in class Point i want to use this widht property from class Shape, so if "point" belong to that list i wish to have possibility to use "container" properties. I also want to serialize then class Shape so I don't think i can use constructor with parameters.

Edit:
I will say how it looks like in my app:
i have class Device

```
class Device
{
string connection;
List<Task> tasks;
}
```

and Task

```
class Task
{
  void DoTask()
  {
     and here i need the connection
  }
}
```

so i just like to do it then foreach(task in task) task.DoTask() but i have to pass additional "this" like task.DoTask(this) or the connection where i think that i should have acces of my container if it allows me.

Comment: Maybe off topic, by why would a Point have a Width?

Comment: how might I acces width from class Point??

Comment: don't care why Point has a widht it is just an example of problem i have

Comment: @kosnkov: The trouble with meaningless examples is that they give no information about the motivation for the desire to do this... without more information, we can't help you change your design to be more appropriate. If this is an example of a real problem you have, try to tell us about that real problem - hiding any intellectual property as required, but still giving a meaningful example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no general concept of the "owner" of an object. After all, the same `Point` reference could appear in several places. The desire to do this usually indicates a design smell. If you need to give the `Point` object more information, that's presumably when you're doing something *with* it - so pass that information to the appropriate method.

Comment: Jon i think sometimes that u are not a human only inteligent stackOverflow bot :)

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest ways would be to build an explicit association between these two. For example:

```
public class Point {

   Shape shape; 

   public Point( Shape shape ) {
      this.shape = shape;
   }

}
```

In this particular implementation each point points to a single shape. And you can of course access shape properties from within the point class.

The serialization should not an issue if you can control it.